# Recycle all apps pools in IIS by command line

Tags: powershell, iis, appcmd

I have a PowerShell script:

`& $psexec $serveraddr -u $remoteuser -p $remotepass -accepteula C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppool /xml | C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool /in`

that I am using to recycle all IIS pools. The problem is that only default, given from IIS pools are recycled. No private pools are recycled. They are not found by the second appcmd. First appcmd finds all pools, given by IIS and private.

Error is:

> ERROR ( message:Nie można odnaleźć obiektu APPPOOL o identyfikatorze "Core1". )

from polish language it is:

> ERROR ( message: Can't find object APPPOOL with id "Core1". )

I can't recycle private pools. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: First `appcmd` invoked by `psexec` on remote computer, but second `appcmd` invoked on local computer. Is that what you want?

Comment: No - this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the second part of the command is executed locally. I've changed the script to recycle every each pool by single commands:

`& $psexec $server -u $remoteuser -p $remotepass -accepteula C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool /apppool.name:Core1`

Answer (score 4):

This is a one liner to recyle **all** Applications Pools :

```
& $env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppools /state:Started /xml | & $env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppools /in
```

Comment: This is a remote server, your answer does not include remoteness of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overkill for your question, but you might be interested in the general alternate approach to do something in parallel on the several servers:

```
$servers=@('server1', 'server2', 'server3')

$recycleAppPools = {
    echo $(Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
    appcmd list apppools /state:Started /xml | appcmd recycle apppools /in
    echo "`n"
}

workflow Perform-Deployment {
    Param ($servers, $actionBlock)

    # Run on all servers in parallel
    foreach -parallel ($server in $servers) {
        "Doing on $server..."
        # Execute script on the server
        InlineScript {
            $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($Using:actionBlock)
            Invoke-Command -computername $Using:server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
        }
    }
}

cls
# Execute workflow
Perform-Deployment $servers $recycleAppPools
```

Moreover, you could pass parameters to your script block, like, for example:

```
$DeployPythonPackage = {
    param($venv, $pythonPackagePath)
    & "$venv\scripts\pip" install --upgrade $pythonPackagePath
}

workflow Perform-Deployment {
    Param ($servers, $actionBlock, $venv, $pythonPackagePath)

    # Run on all servers in parallel
    foreach -parallel ($server in $servers) {
        "Deploying Python package '$pythonPackagePath' on $server..."
        # Execute script on the server
        InlineScript {
            $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($Using:actionBlock)
            Invoke-Command -computername $Using:server -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock `
                -ArgumentList $Using:venv, $Using:pythonPackagePath
        }
    }
}

cls
# Execute workflow
Perform-Deployment $servers $DeployPythonPackage $venv $pythonPackagePath
```

Comment: `The foreach '-parallel' parameter is reserved for future use.` - 7.2.1

Comment: @pbies, so I must have come from the future ;). In fact those are chunks of perfectly working scripts, executed `powershell -file scriptname.ps1`. `foreach -parallel` is part of PowerShell Workflows available since PowerShell 3.0. Look there, for example [PowerShell Workflows: The Basics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-the-basics/)

Comment: PowerShell 7.2.1 tells that -parallel is reserved, but I didn't tried it in workflow. PowerShell 5.1 - tells exactly that I need to use -parallel in workflow.